# Ethereum Mining Simplified (Gas price / mining fees)

Tags: go-ethereum

I've been reading these in-depth explanations of how the gas prices are calculated and looked briefly at the spreadsheet with various variations of gas price per "function" which is still not really clear.

https://whattomine.com/
I'm using the calculator but it's asking for "fee (%)" and I'm still trying to figure out what that is.

Answer (score 0):

Fees are not a fixed percentage they depends on the network usage. It can go from zero if block is empty to several times the block reward. Also it varies a lot sometimes network is busy and fees are high other times network usage is low and so are fees.

- Today at block 11800000 reward is 2 ethers and fees are 3.1 ethers.
- Fifteen days ago at block 11700000 reward was 2 ethers and fees were  2.7 ethers.
- Thirty days ago at block 11600000 reward was 2 ethers and fees were 1.6 ethers.
- Around 277 days ago at block 10000000 reward was 2 ethers and fees were 0.07 ethers.